# Named export 'xxx' not found. The requested module 'xxx' is a CommonJS module

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

After I changed the project to esm by add loader `NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' gulp build` like this, build the typescript project, shows error:

```
> rd-lezer-tex@0.0.1 build
> NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' gulp build

(node:84018) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
file:///Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/packages/lezer-tex/tools/transformers.ts:1
import { isNoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral, isTaggedTemplateExpression, visitEachChild, visitNode, } from 'typescript';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'isNoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral' not found. The requested module 'typescript' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'typescript';
const { isNoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral, isTaggedTemplateExpression, visitEachChild, visitNode, } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:127:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: rd-lezer-tex@0.0.1 
npm ERR!   at location: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/packages/lezer-tex
```

why did this happen? should I chenge the import style one by one?